# Functional analysis with KKT conditions

Tags: optimization, functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to solve an optimization problem `min` $F(x_{ik}) $ subject to $x \in X$. $F$ here is a function or functional that I wish to determine. I want my optimal solution to satisfy certain properties. The goal is to find all such functions which in the optimal solution satisfy this condition I want. Said another way, find me a class of functions which when optimized subject to a set of constraints, gives me a solution satisfying some property.

How do I approach this problem? I can write the KKT conditions for this, but it doesn't get me anywhere. Someone said this may fall in the calculus of variations domain, but I don't know how to use that. What's a good starting point?

Comment: Are you interested in finding solutions from a theoretical point of view, or actually computing them numerically?

Comment: Err, I don't understand then. If F is allowed to vary, then what prevents you from choosing a function $F$ such that $F(x)$ is arbitrarily negative?

Comment: Then choose $F$ to be the function such that $F(x) = -9999\dots$ for all $x \in X$

Comment: Ok, then I recommend the books "Numerical Optimization" by Nocedal and Wright, and "Convex Optimization" by Boyd

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you do not understand the question. I will delete this comment discussion as it is outside of my question's scope.
I know how to solve an optimization model given an objective function. What I do not know is how to solve it for a family of objective functions.

Comment: Would you say that your objective is then $\min_{x,F} F(x)$ such that $x \in X$ and $F \in \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of functions?

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear.